# Change image texture

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to do some pixel manipulation on a image texture of a loaded 3d model.

So I started drawing the image to canvas to get the image data, and re-apply that image to the model. But it seems it lost all its texture coordinates. How can I preserve them?

This is what I have:

```
    let img = clothes.material.emissiveMap.image;

    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

    var new_image = new Image();
    new_image.src = canvas.toDataURL();

    clothes.material.emissiveMap.image = new_image;
    clothes.material.emissiveMap.needsUpdate = true;
    clothes.material.needsUpdate = true;
```

Original

[image]

Modified

[image]

Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use a slightly different workflow:

```js
const img = clothes.material.emissiveMap.image;

const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

clothes.material.emissiveMap.dispose();
clothes.material.emissiveMap = new THREE.CanvasTexture(canvas);
// copy texture parameters if necessary
```

It is not intended to change the `image` reference of an existing texture.

Comment: @Pypax I think you might need to set the [texture.flipY](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/textures/Texture.flipY) property to either `true or false`. See if that changes anything.